# How to change the color.pressed of a Unity button through a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I want to make an inventory with different categories and if a category is selected the button for that category should no longer get a overlay if it is pressed.
I've tried changing the *pressed.color* like this:

```
        Button btn = catogory_inventroy.GetComponent<Button>();
        ...
        btn.colors.pressedColor.a = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

but then it says

> The return value of "ColorBlock.pressedColor" is not a variable and therefore cannot be changed.

I've also tried assigning the value of the new color before, but still doesn't work
So what can I do to fix my probleme?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the ColorBlock struct to the buttons `colors` property.  You cannot modify the value of a property that returns a struct, since what is returned is a new copy of the values and not a reference.

```
var colors = btn.colors;

colors.pressedColor = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

btn.colors = colors;
```